# How to uninstall XAMPP when its not in a root directory?

Tags: apache, xampp

I have accidentally copied my XAMPP files into my Users\ ...\Desktop folder and now cannot uninstall it with the regular installer as it will only work if the files were in the root C:.

Attempting to delete the files with "right click -> delete" don't work either.

I have tried to just have two installations at the same time. One being in the Users\ ...\Desktop and one in C:, but apache still woudln't start.

[Here's the error message in the C:\ version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVmHy.png)

[Here's the error message in the Users..\Desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSW3f.png)

I am more looking for how to uninstall the Users\ ...\Desktop version rather than troubleshoot it but the images might help show the problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I moved the files to a USB stick so they are off my computer (you could probably just delete them normally), then ran cmd as administrator and typed "sc delete "Apache2.4"
and then ran XAMPP and worked a charm